# With NGINX upstreams, is it possible to proxy pass to both HTTP and HTTPS backends in the same upstream?

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-upstreams

Suppose I want to proxy some portion of my traffic to a remote backend instead of the local listener on the server. For example:

```
upstream backends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 weight=20;  # local process (HTTP)
    server other-remote-backend.company-internal.com:443;  # remote server (HTTPS)
}


location / {
    # ...other stuff...
    proxy_pass http://backends;
}
```

In the above configuration, every 20 or so requests NGINX will try to route to `http://other-remote-backend.company-internal.com:443` which is only listening for SSL.

Is there a way for the upstream to define its own protocol scheme? Right now this seems undoable without changing the local listener process to be SSL as well (which is a less than desirable change to make).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is the usual case, I've figured out my own problem and its quite obvious. If you're trying to accomplish the above the trick is quite simple.

1. First create a new NGINX Virtual Host that listens on HTTP and proxy_passes to your remote HTTPS backend like so:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/remote_proxy`

```
upstream remote {
        server other-remote-backend.company-internal.com:443;
}

server {

        # other-remote-backend.company-internal.com:443;

        listen 8181;

        server_name my_original_server_name;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass https://remote;
        }

}
```

2. You can now use just `http` for your upstreams in the original configuration listening on 443:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
upstream backends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 weight=20;  # local process (HTTP)
    server 127.0.0.1:8181 # local nginx proxying to HTTPS remote
}


location / {
    # ...other stuff...
    proxy_pass http://backends;
}
```

Now just enable your new site and restart
`$ ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/remote_proxy /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ && systemctl restart nginx`